# How come C++ project in Visual Studio Community 2015 only contain Universal Apps?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

First, let me show you what I have..

1. Visual Studio Community 2015 installed with customization as follows..
   [image: VS2015 custom install with native language support only]
2. Windows 10 Home (x64)

I tried creating C++ project with Win32 and standard C++11 support but I couldn't find any under "File > New > Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C++ > Windows". (Universal Windows App is the only option here ...)
[image: only "Universal Windows Platform" available under C++]

I wish that the subpaths under my "File > New > Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C++ > Windows" have all three items that Visual C# and Basic already have underneath ("Universal", "Windows 8", "Classic Desktop"). To be more specific, I wish my "Visual C++ > Windows" to look like this..
[image]

I know that I can code Win32/C++ using "Universal Windows Apps" template but Win32 support is limited and it comes with bunch of .Net stuff that I don't need. Please don't get me wrong, I do love .Net and WPF and I myself was once a C# programmer (WinForm in particular) and I think of .Net to be the future of Windows development but right now I need to start with empty project with Win32/C++ support.

Is this problem confined to Community version only? (anyone tried VS2015 Pro/Ent ? please let me know)

EDIT:
Definitely can't be a solution to this problem.. but I found that I can circumvent the problem as below:
[image]

Here's how it works. Instead of searching for templates in "Installed > Visual C++ > Windows", I just go to "Installed > Samples > Visual C++ > Desktop" and Hurray! I see a Win32 "C++ UTF-8 Conversion Helpers" sample. I'll just use it to create projects and then discard anything unnecessary to make it empty. One hell of a pathetic approach just to get an empty C++ project :(

EDIT:
I posted the same [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/513c99c9-0688-44ae-b076-799a1dc7ac95/how-come-c-project-in-visual-studio-community-2015-only-contain-universal-apps?forum=vcgeneral&prof=required) on Microsoft Developer Network. After another day of trials and errors, [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-Y3lha2Raa19qTG8/view?usp=sharing) is the furthest I went. Still no sign of "Classic Desktop" under C++

Comment: VS2015 Enterprise works just fine, all needed is displayed. Though I installed some of the `Common Tools` too, but that shouldn't matter IMO. Did you try to ask in the [Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=vcgeneral&filter=alllanguages) yet ?

Comment: @Blacktempel I haven't yet tried asking in Microsoft Forum (may be I felt guilty of trying to get support for free software like vs community..), but I did search for an answer for at least 2 to 3 days or so... Anyway thx for telling me about ent version. If ent works, then pro will as well IMO.

Comment: I have exactly your setup and have created a Win32 C++ console application without problems. In the new project options it was under "other languages" (or something like that, sorry I don't have it in front of me right now).

Comment: @DavidLee If nothing works in the end, consider a clean re-install.

Comment: Not sure what's going on lately, they are constantly tinkering with Community to keep the download size reasonably small.  There were two distinct versions, "For Windows" only had the modern UI templates, "For Desktop" had the legacy templates.  Looks like you picked the wrong one.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree. [A Note from Steve Carroll, VC++ Dev Manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers.aspx) shows that VS team were indeed focused on reducing the download size. However, I don't think there are two distinct version of VS community. I don't know about 2013 but for 2015 I'm pretty sure that it comes in one single installer.

Comment: @Blacktempel, I think this is my third time clean-installing vs_community. First round, I did a typicall install by following the installer wizard. Second round, I downloaded the whole package to be installed offline using `vs_community.exe /layout` and then installed the package with C++ support using `vs_community.exe /q /norestart /InstallSelectableItems NativeLanguageSupport_Group`. All three rounds failed to show "Win32, C++, MFC or any native C++ stuff" underneath "File > New > Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C++ > Windows".

Comment: After another day of trials and errors, [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-Y3lha2Raa19qTG8/view?usp=sharing) is the furthest I went. Still no sign of "Classic Desktop" under C++

Comment: You probably need to add Windows and Web development.  Direct X etc is all Windows development

Comment: Could someone be kind enough to post a screenshot of VS Community with working evidence of having "Classic Desktop" underneath C++ project ? Just wanna make sure what I aim to search for does exist.

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I found an answer to this problem....

I was so stupid to keep on launching vs-community using the wrong shortcut.

If you want to see all the C++ templates (including win32,MFC,ATL,...), you must use the shortcut "Visual Studio 2015" not the "Blend for Visual Studio 2015" ([screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-MTRVT2ZhbXE0c1U/view?usp=sharing))

There are two shortcuts after you install Visual Studio Community 2015.
As you [see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-TzlUbDI5RVg1bGM/view?usp=sharing), they each point to the different [target](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-TzlUbDI5RVg1bGM/view?usp=sharing).
So you need to use the shortcut that runs "devenv.exe" not the "Blend.exe".

But its strange that the first launch after the [ISO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-c0VxOG1JaDhzbFk/view?usp=sharing) installation launches "[devenv.exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3eOkW7ft8-TzlUbDI5RVg1bGM/view?usp=sharing)" but the web installer(vs_community.exe) launches "Blend.exe".

I guess I'm the only one here who made such a stupid mistake.
May be I should delete this question if not so many find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, however, the only way i was able to get win32 c++ was to install the c++ packages.[image]

Comment: Thx for the screenshot. Now I know that what I aim to search does exist. Anyway, I apparently did install C++ packages by [custom install](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qV2XV.png). That screenshot of yours is "Visual Studio Community 2015" not the retail "Visual Studio 2015 Pro/Ent..." right ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a separate installer, but I wouldn't doubt it, there's usually more than one way to go about these kind of things

Comment: I was launching the wrong shortcut. The proper shortcut named "Visual Studio 2015" launches "devenv.exe" which will show what you posted. I was stupid enough to launch from the wrong shorcut named "Blend for Visual Studio". BTW, I got a clue for the answer from the bluish theme of your screenshot.

Comment: Well, i solved this lost of win32 console  by select the ```Visual C++ ```and just double click the opition ```Install Universal Windows Platform Tools``` on the right panel ,and installed that.

Comment: @NilDroid Yes you are right. But no if you run the wrong shortcut. Beware of the shortcut "Blend for Visual Studio", since it will continue to hide the empty C++ project no matter how much C++ stuff you add into vs_community (including the `Install Universal Windows Platform Tools` you just mentioned). Rules of Thumb.. always run the shortcut that runs `devenv.exe` not `Blend.exe`. `devenv.exe` has been the entry point for all vs products since early 2000